# Shared Layout view not applying to all views in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

Layout view not shared across other views
Currently my home page and other main pages share the view of my layout however the other pages such as the login page share the view but with no styling or images. Also my main pages such as about for example all the crud features like delete also remove styling, anyone know how to link this all together?
[Actual View of login page and Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL4jG.jpg)
Login.cshtml

```
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form method="post">
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                            <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>
                        <a asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Clean Blog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="post.html">Sample Post</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Header -->
    <!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
    <header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('img/home-bg.jpg')">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1>Clean Blog</h1>
                        <hr class="small">
                        <span class="subheading">A Clean Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As @hiiru mentions, the problem is one of relativity.  You have to understand that the server does not render your CSS, the browser does.  And the browser references the CSS based on the current URL.  One option is to use the root relative marker "~/blah/blah/blah.css".  This only works in MVC versions since (IIRC) MVC4, but since you're using core it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Layout.cshtml the path to the css files are relative.
Change them to absolute (by adding a leading / to the CSS paths) and it should work.

The problem is that the main page is on /, so the CSS directory is /css.
However other pages might be at /Account/Login, so the CSS directory would be /Account/Login/css (which is wrong)

Assuming that the folders /css and /vendor are correct:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="~/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="~/css/clean-blog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="~/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

the same applies to the JS scripts at the end:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="~/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
<script src="~/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/contact_me.js"></script>

<!-- Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="~/js/clean-blog.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A better method is to user site root relative addressing ~/foo, which will help if the site is moved into a sub-application.  Another option is to use the content helper (@Html.Content("~/...") which is only necessary on older versions of Razer (pre-mvc4).

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch you're right, thanks for the input.  I updated my code sample