# My css styles only apply to my index page in my ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I created my own CSS styles and added it to `wwwroot/css`. I have added the links to my `_Layout.cshtml`. The page called when the program is run is the `index.cshtml` and everything works fine there.

But when you click to move to the next pages none of the styles apply including bootstrap.

This is the head in my `_Layout.cshtml`.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - FIDEL ENTERPRISE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Final_WebApplication.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

I have tried to link the CSS file to each page but that doesn't work.

Comment: Abiy - I think you may want to look at this (if you haven't already): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080261/shared-layout-view-not-applying-to-all-views-in-asp-net-core-2-1

Comment: Replace `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />` with `<link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />` - add the `~/` to reference the CSS starting at the root

Comment: Hi @Abiy, have you use `@{ Layout = "_Layout";}` in each page or add globally in _ViewStart.cshtml?